# java dropdown calculated number to post to next page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form with dropdown select, each selection adds the value to calculate a total. I did so with the script below:

```js
$(function(){
    $("select.calculate").on("change", calc);
    $("input[type=checkbox].calculate").on("click", calc);
    function calc() {
        var basePrice = 60;
        newPrice = basePrice;
        $("select.calculate option:selected, input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function () {
            newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
        });

        newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
        $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" input name="test" class="calculate">
    <option data-price="0" value=" ">0</option>
    <option data-price="70" value="Test x 1">1</option>
    <option data-price="140" value="Test x 2">2</option>
    <option data-price="210" value="Test x 3">3</option>
</select>

<span id="item-price">0</span>
```

It works great on the page, but I want to carry the total number forward to the next page, like how I would carry the chosen choices. I am using the POST method, so far the next page is able to get the choices I made via POST.

But I can't seem to figure out how I would go about getting the total number to be carried forward to next page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to save the value in hidden field and then post to the next page just like below

```
<input type='hidden' name='item_price' value='' id='item_price_val'>
```

change your jquery function with

```
$(function(){
$("select.calculate").on("change", calc);
$("input[type=checkbox].calculate").on("click", calc);
    function calc() {
        var basePrice = 60;
        newPrice = basePrice;
        $("select.calculate option:selected, input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function () {
            newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
        });

        newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
        $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
        $("#item_price_val").val(newPrice);

    }
});
```

and on PHP page get the value from the input variable like

```
$item_price = $_POST['item_price'];
```

I hope it will works for you.

Comment: Wow. It worked. Thanks. I do have one problem however, I have a base price of $60, however when I get on the page, its shows zero, only when selections are made, does it jump to the value amount. I had a workaround by adding <span id="item-price">60</span> for my total, so it appears as 60 when I get on the page, and changes if selections are made, but now, if no selections are made, i will post to the next page, and it will be left blank, only if selections are made will a value appear, any way to fix that?

Comment: please ask another questionn and accept this answer if it works :-)

Comment: i have accepted it, i would vote up but I do not have enough reputations yet. Thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979044/form-calculator-script-base-price-not-loading-onload

I have a new question you can answer if you want.