# Form Calculator Script Base Price Not Loading OnLoad

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a calulcator in my form to calculate my dropdown options choices.

```
$(function() {
  $("select.calculate").on("change", calc);
  $("input[type=checkbox].calculate").on("click", calc);

  function calc() {
    var basePrice = 60;
    newPrice = basePrice;
    $("select.calculate option:selected, input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function() {
      newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    });

    newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
    $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
    $("#item_price_val").val(newPrice);

  }
});
```

and in html to get the number out I have it as:

```
<span id="item-price">0</span>
```

problem is, i have the baseprice at 60, however when i get on the page, its zero. only when i make selections will the price go up. how do i get the baseprice to appear from the beginning at page load?

I need it to start as base price as those selections are not required, so if I do not choose those, i will click submit form, and it submits zero dollars instead of 60 dollars.

Comment: You can make a call to `calc()` when document is ready.

Comment: didnt seem to work. how and where would you add the call?

Comment: don't use tags that people follow such as myself if there's no (php) code for it, same goes for the html tag/forms. There is no relevant code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var basePrice = 60; 
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("select.calculate").on("change", calc);
 $("input[type=checkbox].calculate").on("click", calc);
 $("#item-price").html(basePrice);
 $("#item_price_val").val(basePrice);
});
function calc() {
newPrice = basePrice;
$("select.calculate option:selected,input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function() {
  newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
});
newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
$("#item-price").html(newPrice);
$("#item_price_val").val(newPrice);
}
```

Please Use an updated version of your code.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Slight problem though, on page load it appears as "$60" but when I update my form selection it always appears as "$80.00" How do i get rid of that .00 decimal point unless, or if not, how do i make it start from "$60.00" instead of "$60". I tried adding 60.00 to my base price, that didnt work.

Comment: chaeck with this attribute $(this).data('price') . what is that returning. or use newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(0); that will remove additional point value.

Comment: Oh wait small problem. When I have calculated everything and click submit to next page, everything goes through, but when i press "back" i go back to this page, and it resets at $60 starting base, with the options already chosen, so it kinda leaves a loophole where they click back and submit again, the chosen items are there, but price is as if they didnt choose anything.

Comment: not understand. what is your requirement? can you please share a place where I can see your code. but if you want that value back when you press back you have to store it in a cookie in a JSON array. and retrieve it in page load

Comment: Something like in the javascript there is var baseprice = 60 followed by 
 $("select.calculate").on("change", calc);
is there a code that select.calculate on pageload? 
so if no selections were made it is 60, but if selections were made, it will already calculate any movement in the select options dropdown. because when i click next, and back again, i get back to this page, with selections already been made, but the price is back to base price. (or if that is not possible, anyway to always load page with all options reset)

Comment: Above code will reset all values with default if page is loaded back. No need to do extra functionality. But if you want to do selection value back then you have to use cookies to store and retrieve values