# Calculate script for forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script to calculate the form selections, it works perfectly. However its set to calculate starting from a base price of $60.

Is there a way I can get it to start with a base price of a previous page?

Like if Page1.php has this calculator and I make the selections and end up with a final number of 102, I click submit, and on page2.php there are more options to choose, so there is another calculator function to calculate the form, but it starts from the base price of the previous page instead of a fixed $60 base price.

```js
var basePrice = 60;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.calculate").on("change", calc);
  $("input[type=checkbox].calculate").on("click", calc);
  $("#item-price").html(basePrice);
  $("#item_price_val").val(basePrice);
});

function calc() {
  newPrice = basePrice;
  $("select.calculate option:selected,input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function() {
    newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
  });
  newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
  $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
  $("#item_price_val").val(newPrice);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- The HTML to get the calculated price to appear -->
<span id="item-price">0</span>
<input type='hidden' name='item_price' value='' id='item_price_val'>
```

Comment: where is the php for this?

Comment: @ Funk Forty Niner is right need the PHP to pass the info.

Comment: When you press submit, the input fields from the form get sent to the action page via the $_POST variable in PHP (well assuming method="post").  Use this to get your starting price from one page to the other.  FYI: if I understood your question.  It is a bit convoluted, maybe I missunderstood...

Comment: Don't use tags that people follow such as myself if there's no (php) code for it. There is no relevant code here. Edit: I removed the php tag.

Comment: This looks closely related to a previous question you posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979044/form-calculator-script-base-price-not-loading-onload

Comment: Sorry for adding the php tag. My bad. I am using php in it to get the post but didn't feel its necessary to post that line here as its a standard php post. My question was mainly about having the base price instead of a fixed number, it would be a number from a previous page, which requires php to post over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out, to anyone who needs to know it was as simple as changing

```
var basePrice = 60;
```

to

```
var basePrice = <?php $name = $_POST["item_price"]; echo $name; ?>;
```